# Magento1 format string to date

Tags: magento-1.9

I want format from string to date. How can i do?

```
public function checkTimeCourse(){

    $modelCoure = Mage::getModel('course/courses')->getCollection();
    $modelCoure->getSelect();
    $toDay = date('Y-m-d');echo $toDay; //2020-05-19
    foreach($modelCoure as $item){
        $dateTo = date($item->getDateTo()); // select from database string(2020-05-25)
        $checkDay = $toDay - $dateTo;
        var_dump($dateTo);
    }exit();
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
strtotime($item->getDateTo())
```

Comment: Yes i have try but it will output int(1590362780)

Comment: And i try date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item->getDateTo())); but it output int(0)

Comment: if you dump `$item->getDateTo()` what is the output?

Comment: if i dump it will output string(10) "2020-05-25"

Comment: what does `$checkDay` do?

Comment: i want select today, and select dateTo from database.I will subtract them. $checkDay = $today - $dateTo

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the date difference of `$today` and `$dateTo` ?

Comment: Yes right. I want do it..

Comment: try this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-date_diff-function/